# VHDL Pullup Resisters

Tags: vhdl

I am fairly new to vhdl, I am working to understand if I can use it for a project.

I created a project to see how to implement pullup resisters and see how they work.  I must have done something wrong.

My constraints entry for the wire is

```
net "rx_i" PULLUP;
net "rx_i" loc="p88";
```

the process for the project is

```
Process (clk_i)
 type state_type is (qInit, qZero, qZero1, qZero2, qZero3, qZero4);
 variable state: state_type:= qInit;

Begin
if (rising_edge(clk_i)) then
  case state is
    when qInit =>
      if (rx_i = '0') then
        led_o(0) <= '1';
        state := qZero;
      end if;

    when qZero =>
      if (rx_i = '0') then
        led_o(1) <= '1';
        state := qZero1;
      end if;

    when qZero1 =>
      if (rx_i = '0') then
        led_o(2) <= '1';
        state := qZero2;
      end if;

    when qZero2 =>
      if (rx_i = '0') then
        led_o(3) <= '1';
        state := qZero3;
      end if;

    when qZero3 =>
      if (rx_i = '0') then
        led_o(4) <= '1';
        state := qZero4;
      end if;

    when qZero4 =>
      if (rx_i = '0') then
        led_o(5) <= '1';
        state := qInit;
      end if;

    end case;

end if;

End Process;
```

All of the led's 0 thru 5 light up.  If the wire is pulled up high I would expect maybe a few spurious 0's but not 6 in a row.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First: you never set the value of your leds back to '0'. Once you have set all values to '1' in this state machine, you keep driving '1'. You could add a line like `led_o <= (others => '0');` before your case statement.

Even then, you will be running through the states at the speed of your clock. Your leds will be blinking so fast that your eyes just sees them as "on", but slightly less bright. perhaps you can add a counter in each state, or check for another condition like a button pushed.

Finally, the code you have posted shows nothing of a pull-up. I'm just assuming you are using that in another part of your code. The problems I can see have nothing to do with pull-ups.

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints file is only used when the code gets synthesized and turned into a bitstream to be loaded onto the FPGA.  It has nothing to do with simulation.  In simulation you can create a pullup by driving 'H' (high) onto a signal.

If you want led_o to be the signal pulled up you could do:

```
led_o <= 'H';
led_o <= LED_DRIVE;
```

So when LED_DRIVE is high impedance (Z) then the pullup will take over and pull the signal high.  This is how you would implement a bidirectional interface such as I2C.  But I think now that I've gone over your head.  The tutorial here shows how you could create a simple LED blinker: http://www.nandland.com/vhdl/tutorials/tutorial-your-first-vhdl-program-part1.html